# Custom Spring boot Exception handler not working when hosted in cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a newbie in spring boot and I have a scenario I cant figure out what I could be missing. I have created Common Error handler class to handle all my application errors and this work fine either when am using the spring boot embedded tomcat or local tomcat. But If I deploy the same war file to my digital ocean cloud server where have installed tomcat application does not call the @ControllerAdvice. Here is my spring boot code which I need help in to figure out what I could be missing or what I should do. In my cloud server am using open jdk 8 but on localhost am using jdk8

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
{
   
   @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> InvalidData(ValidationException e){
        common.logException(e);
        return response(common.BAD_REQUEST, "125# "+e.getMessage());
        
    }

   private ResponseEntity<ServerResponse> response(int code, String msg) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ServerResponse(code,msg
              ), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);


    }



}

@Getter
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
public class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {

    private Object[] params = null;
    private String status_code;

    public ValidationException(String message,String status_code) {
        super(message);
        this.status_code=status_code;
    }

    public ValidationException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public ValidationException(String message, Object[] params) {
        super(message);
        this.params = params;
    }



}
@Data
public class RegModel{
    @JsonProperty("EmailAddress")
    private String email_address;
    private String application_type;
    private String admission_num;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ResponseModel{
    private int resp_code;
    private String message;
}

@Service
public class MyService{

  public <T> T createStudent(RegModel userCreationModel)
    {
        T response=null;

        if(userCreationModel.getEmail_address()==null)
        {


            throw new ValidationException(new ResponseModel("Invalid Request",500);
        }
     }

}
```

and here is my post man request using local host
[image]

and here is deployed war file in cloud response same end points
[image]

Comment: If your application code isn't confidential, please upload your repo to github and share the repo link. That will drastically increase the chances of getting help

Comment: @Ilam the code is kinda confidential